# Debugging system-related application errors in Linux

Tags: linux

I am now faced with trying to debug some odd crashes for a commercial application, the dreaded SAS, and I am looking for some clues that might help to diagnose the issue.

Of course I check the SAS runtime logs, and I also check /var/log/messages.  Nothing in /var/log/messages, but the SAS runtime log seems to indicate a memory or disk space issue:

```
ERROR: Insufficient space in file WORK.'#tf0533'n.UTILITY.
ERROR: Insufficient space in file WORK.20110609_BCH.DATA.
```

There is **surely enough** disk space, so I am lead to believe it might be a memory issue.  What other system logs or even tools can I use for looking for further information (such as writing to a full disk device, spikes in memory usage, swapfs errors, etc.)?

Comment: Can you get your application to show full paths? Maybe you have enough space on your data filesystem but `/tmp` got full at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can trace system calls via `strace` and calls to library functions via `ltrace`.